# Get Query String Value in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this URL

```
var url = "/test/Create/" + $("#hdnFlag").val() +"?CmpT="+"Ilim";
window.location.href = url;
```

and in my Test controller I do this to get query string value

```
 tM_PMO.Type = Request.QueryString["CmpT"];
```

But always give me null values.

Comment: Have you configured any custom routes in your route table?

Comment: @Devilscomrade i don't understand  u i'am beginning in mvc

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the `GET` and `POST` types.

`Query string` can be read with the URL of the `GET` request. However, you cannot read the Query string value in the URL when you make a `POST` request. For this you need to submit it to the server.

Below I give you a few examples of usage.

**GET Request**
You can read Query string with URL as below

```
public ActionResult Test(string CmpT)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CmpT))
    {
        //your codes...
    }else
    { }
    return View();
}
```

**POST Request**
If you are making a `POST` request and trying to read from the URL, it will return null. In order to read it, you need to send this value to the server as follows.

**1st way** : In your Html.BeginForm in your View Below, submit Query string as below and read this value as Action parameter

View Page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "XController", new { returnUrl = Request.QueryString["CmpT"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Test(string returnUrl)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
    {
        //your codes...
    }else
    { }
    return View();
}
```

**2nd way** : Create a hidden form element as part of the form between the Html.BeginForm tags in your view page and give its value as a query string. Then call it in Action method like below.

View Page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "XController", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.QueryString["CmpT"])
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Test(string returnUrl)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
    {
        //your codes...
    }else
    { }
    return View();
}
```

or for multiple form items (You can also access other form elements this way)

```
public ActionResult Test(FormCollection fc)
{
    string _returnUrl = fc["returnUrl"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_returnUrl))
    {
        //your codes...
    }else
    { }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are looking for below code sample where we just fetch the value in url which we says `query string`:

```
Request.QueryString["querystringparamname"].ToString();
```

You can assign this in any `Var` and use accordingly.

Comment: Is it something wrong with the answer, i just replied becuase question was not clear that's i made this reply as seeing the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but I guess if OP is getting null value and you add a `.ToString()` by the end, it's going to raise an error [NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/4660186). Cannot call a method on a null reference object.